# Insert document on CosmosDB through Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using `Invoke-RestMethod` to make a post request to create a new document in CosmosDB. So far I followed theses links: [Invoking Rest API using PowerShell - CosmosDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45456029/invoking-rest-api-using-powershell-cosmosdb)
, [Add a Document to CosmosDB via the REST API using PowerShell](http://www.jbmurphy.com/2019/02/28/add-a-document-to-cosmosdb-via-the-rest-api-using-powershell/) and the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/create-a-document).

My script retrieves an object like this from external service:

```
{
   "ObjectId": "bd33f6b5-a066-4f0f-8d1b-291a6a2b90ba",
   "Date":  "\/Date(1589379850000)\/",
   "Data": "{\"CreationTime\":\"2019-06-13T13:21:55\",\"Id\":\"e985f142-9359-4ebf-a319-7fa30b6c9987\", \"Fields\":[{\"Name\":\"foo\",\"Value\":\"bar\"}]}"
}
```

My objective is to post the field `Data` into cosmos. To this I extract this field using: `$payload | Select-Object -expand Data`. (I have the above json as PowerShell object). Since this extracted object is a string, I passed it to `Invoke-RestMethod`:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method $Verb -Uri $queryUri -Headers $headers -Body $payload
```

But I keeping getting a `Bad Request` status. I've also tried the following:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method $Verb -Uri $queryUri -Headers $headers -Body ($payload | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)
Invoke-RestMethod -Method $Verb -Uri $queryUri -Headers $headers -Body ($payload | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)
```

Note: I was able to deserialize this string in `C#` using `newtonsoft` (I made a function to receive the PowerShell request). I also was able to insert this document via Postman. Looks like the issue is in the body of the request, since using the PowerShell code generated by Postman worked for me.

Edit: I am passing the content type (`"application/json"`) in header of the request. It also fails when pass it I directly to the `Invoke-RestMethod`

Can someone give a light? To me it should work fine.

Comment: It looks like you are sending Mongo data. The REST API is for the Core SQL API, so you are missing the required "id" attribute?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta, that's right! I was passing the attrbute 'Id' instead of 'id'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your payload is missing the required `id` attribute:

[image: required attributes]

Remember that the REST API is for the Core SQL API operations. Your payload seems to be for a Mongo document?

Make sure you are also passing the partition key. Reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/PowerShellRestApi/PowerShellScripts/CreateItem.ps1

Comment: that's right! I was passing the attrbute 'Id' instead of 'id'. Changing this property solved form me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The data seems to be double converted, to extract it you can use this:

```bsh
$json = '{"ObjectId": "bd33f6b5-a066-4f0f-8d1b-291a6a2b90ba", "Date":  "\/Date(1589379850000)\/", "Data": "{\"CreationTime\":\"2019-06-13T13:21:55\",\"Id\":\"e985f142-9359-4ebf-a319-7fa30b6c9987\", \"Fields\":[{\"Name\":\"foo\",\"Value\":\"bar\"}]}"}'
$data = $json | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Data" | ConvertFrom-Json
$body = $data | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
```

So now `$body` is a proper JSON object which can be send by the `Invoke-RestMethod`:

```bsh
Invoke-RestMethod -Method $verb -Uri $queryUri -Headers $headers -Body $payload -ContentType "application/json"
```